# after switching to zsh from bash receiving: parse error near `PROMPT_COMMAND=vim'

Tags: bash, zsh, neovim

code around `PROMPT_COMMAND=vim' in the .zprofile I am trying to source is:

```
function vim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/bin/vim "$1" } PROMPT_COMMAND=vim
function nvim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/local/bin/nvim "$1"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=nvim
```

This is the only instance of PROMPT_COMMAND=vim in the file.

This worked fine when I was using .bash_profile. It broke when I set up zsh and migrated this to .zprofile. Same result happens if I use .zshrc instead of .zprofile.

The goal of this code is to use nvim whenever I type in vim to ease the migration to nvim and speed up typing.

I am very new to programming so this may be a low level question, but I could not find an answer online.

Comment: Different shells - different languages. You can't really expect your `bash` code to work in `zsh` right out of the box. Perhaps helpful: [What's the ZSH equivalent of BASH's $PROMPT_COMMAND?](https://superuser.com/q/735660/1050422)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit long for a comment, plus format matters ...

I got the following to work in `bash`:

```
function vim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/bin/vim "$1"; } ; PROMPT_COMMAND=vim      # add a ";" before function's ending "}"
                                                   # and separate trailing "}" from the next command

# or 

function vim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/bin/vim "$1"
}; PROMPT_COMMAND=vim                              # place function's ending "}" on a new line
                                                   # but also separate the "}" and the next command

# or

function vim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/bin/vim "$1"
}                                                  # again, place trailing "}" on separate line
PROMPT_COMMAND=vim                                 # place next command on it's own line
```

As pointed out in Ted's comment ... `PROMPT_COMMAND=vim` may not do the same thing in `bash` as it did in `zsh` ...

Comment: It works! This is brilliant, thank you. I'm a super noob so something this easy to follow along is invaluable. For reference: This work equally well in my .bash_profile and my .zprofile.